# How to escape reserved keywords in DynamoDB ExecuteStatementRequest?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I'm trying to issue an update ExecuteStatementRequest using DynamoDB and Java SDK 2.0. I'm struggling to escape keywords that are columns in my table schema.

The following statement:

```java
var response = client.executeStatement(ExecuteStatementRequest.builder()
                .statement("""
                    UPDATE "my-table"
                    SET value=12.5
                    WHERE assignmentId='item1#123#item2#456#item3#789'
                    RETURNING ALL NEW *
                    """)
                .build());
```

When I run the following statement (notice that `value` column is a [reserved keyword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.reserved.html)) I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main"
> software.amazon.awssdk.services.dynamodb.model.DynamoDbException:
> Statement wasn't well formed, can't be processed: Expected identifier
> for simple path (Service: DynamoDb, Status Code: 400, Request ID: XXX)

If instead of `value` I change the column name to `val`, the statement works fine. I know that in `UdateItem` operations I can pass in an array of `expressionAttributeNames` to replace keywords with aliases. Is there a similar primitive I can use for `ExecuteStatementRequest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation you link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/ql-reference.reserved.html) explicitly says what you need to do:

> You can use a reserved keyword as a quoted identifier with double
> quotation marks (for example, `"user"`).

That is the SQL standard way of escaping reserved words. In other words, use `"value"` (or possibly `"VALUE"`) in your statement instead of `value`.

Comment: You are right, I didn't read carefully that page because I was misleading by the insert statement that works with keywords: `INSERT INTO "my-table" VALUE {'assignmentId': 'item1#123#item2#456#item3#789', 'value': 10.0}` and the way `UpdateItem`works. Thanks Mark